# CAML in Powershell with IN CLause

Tags: powershell, csom, caml

I'm using SP 2013 on-premises and I'm wanting to query a list for items by passing a number of IDs to the list and then returning only the Title field. This is executing in Powershell. I have the following that I am using as the ViewXml:

```
        <View>
         <ViewFields>
         <FieldRef Name='Title'/>
        </ViewFields>
 <Query>
  <Where>
   <In>
    <FieldRef Name='ID' />
       <Values>
        <Value Type='Counter'>1131</Value>
        <Value Type='Counter'>478</Value>
        <Value Type='Counter'>360</Value>
       <Values>
   </In>
  </Where>
 </Query>
</View>
```

I get the following when running $ctx.executeQuery();
Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Cannot complete this action.

Please try again."

Here is the rest of the code minus the variable definitions and the bit where the client dlls are added

```
$pwd = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString  
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteURL)  
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($userId, $pwd)

$vFields = "<Value Type='Counter'>1131</Value><Value Type='Counter'>478</Value><Value Type='Counter'>360</Value>";

try{  
    $lists = $ctx.web.Lists ;
    $list = $lists.GetByTitle($ListName);  
    $query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery;
    $xmlCAML = "<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/></ViewFields><Query><Where><In><FieldRef Name='ID'/><Values>$vFields<Values></In></Where></Query></View>";
    write-host $xmlCAML -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $query.ViewXml = $xmlCAML

    $listItems = $list.GetItems($query);  
    $ctx.load($listItems);       
    $ctx.executeQuery();  

    foreach($listItem in $listItems)  
    {  
        Write-Host "Title - " $listItem["Title"]  
    }  
}  
catch{  
    write-host "$($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor red  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you haven't already sorted this, it's just a single-keystroke fix, you've just failed to properly close the `<Values>...</Values>` element in your CAML. Needs to be:

```
<View>
     <ViewFields>
         <FieldRef Name='Title'/>
     </ViewFields>
 <Query>
  <Where>
   <In>
    <FieldRef Name='ID' />
       <Values>
        <Value Type='Counter'>1131</Value>
        <Value Type='Counter'>478</Value>
        <Value Type='Counter'>360</Value>
       </Values> <!-- <== Here :) -->
   </In>
  </Where>
 </Query>
</View>
```